# Get all Salesforce's users

Tags: soql, query, user, c#, bulk-api

I'm writing a software in C# that need to pull all the information about the users in Salesforce (`Id`, `Username`, all other attributes).

I want to use the `Bulk API` and think my query should be:

```
SELECT AboutMe,AccountId,Address,Alias,BadgeText,BannerPhotoUrl,CallCenterId,City,CommunityNickname,CompanyName,ContactId,Country,CreatedById,CreatedDate,DefaultGroupNotificationFrequency,DelegatedApproverId,Department,DigestFrequency,Division,Email,EmailEncodingKey,EmailPreferencesAutoBcc,EmailPreferencesAutoBccStayInTouch,EmailPreferencesStayInTouchReminder,EmployeeNumber,Extension,Fax,FederationIdentifier,FirstName,ForecastEnabled,FullPhotoUrl,GeocodeAccuracy,Id,IsActive,IsProfilePhotoActive,JigsawImportLimitOverride,LanguageLocaleKey,LastLoginDate,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,LastName,LastPasswordChangeDate,LastReferencedDate,LastViewedDate,Latitude,LocaleSidKey,Longitude,ManagerId,MediumPhotoUrl,MobilePhone,Name,OfflinePdaTrialExpirationDate,OfflineTrialExpirationDate,Phone,PostalCode,ProfileId,ReceivesAdminInfoEmails,ReceivesInfoEmails,SenderEmail,SenderName,Signature,SmallPhotoUrl,State,StayInTouchNote,StayInTouchSignature,StayInTouchSubject,Street,SystemModstamp,TimeZoneSidKey,Title,Username,UserPermissionsCallCenterAutoLogin,UserPermissionsInteractionUser,UserPermissionsJigsawProspectingUser,UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser,UserPermissionsMarketingUser,UserPermissionsMobileUser,UserPermissionsOfflineUser,UserPermissionsSFContentUser,UserPermissionsSiteforceContributorUser,UserPermissionsSiteforcePublisherUser,UserPermissionsSupportUser,UserPermissionsWorkDotComUserFeature,UserPreferencesActivityRemindersPopup,UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode,UserPreferencesCacheDiagnostics,UserPreferencesContentEmailAsAndWhen,UserPreferencesContentNoEmail,UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail,UserPreferencesDisableBookmarkEmail,UserPreferencesDisableChangeCommentEmail,UserPreferencesDisableEndorsementEmail,UserPreferencesDisableFeedbackEmail,UserPreferencesDisableFileShareNotificationsForApi,UserPreferencesDisableFollowersEmail,UserPreferencesDisableLaterCommentEmail,UserPreferencesDisableLikeEmail,UserPreferencesDisableMentionsPostEmail,UserPreferencesDisableMessageEmail,UserPreferencesDisableProfilePostEmail,UserPreferencesDisableSharePostEmail,UserPreferencesDisableWorkEmail,UserPreferencesDisCommentAfterLikeEmail,UserPreferencesDisMentionsCommentEmail,UserPreferencesDisProfPostCommentEmail,UserPreferencesEnableAutoSubForFeeds,UserPreferencesEventRemindersCheckboxDefault,UserPreferencesHideBiggerPhotoCallout,UserPreferencesHideChatterOnboardingSplash,UserPreferencesHideCSNDesktopTask,UserPreferencesHideCSNGetChatterMobileTask,UserPreferencesHideEndUserOnboardingAssistantModal,UserPreferencesHideLightningMigrationModal,UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI,UserPreferencesHideSecondChatterOnboardingSplash,UserPreferencesHideSfxWelcomeMat,UserPreferencesJigsawListUser,UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred,UserPreferencesPathAssistantCollapsed,UserPreferencesPreviewLightning,UserPreferencesReminderSoundOff,UserPreferencesShowCityToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowCityToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowCountryToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowCountryToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowEmailToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowEmailToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowFaxToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowFaxToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowManagerToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowManagerToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowMobilePhoneToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowMobilePhoneToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowPostalCodeToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowPostalCodeToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowProfilePicToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowStateToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowStateToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowStreetAddressToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowStreetAddressToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowTitleToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowTitleToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesShowWorkPhoneToExternalUsers,UserPreferencesShowWorkPhoneToGuestUsers,UserPreferencesSortFeedByComment,UserPreferencesTaskRemindersCheckboxDefault,UserRoleId,UserType FROM User
```

For some reason, i'm getting the following error for my batch:

> stateMessage=InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED: Selecting compound data not supported in Bulk Query

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

My software is working with simple query (like ‘select Username from user’).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your query to work independent of version, query the fields individually. <s>If you want to query the compound fields, make sure you are using the most recent API Version.</s> As @Eric notes, the `Bulk API` does not support this behavior at any level, so you need to query the individual fields for it to work no matter what.

Querying the individual fields would look like:

```
SELECT City, Street, State, PostalCode, Country FROM User
```

---

## Reference

> ### [Address Compound Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm):
>
> Standard addresses—addresses built into standard objects in Salesforce—are accessible in the SOAP and REST APIs as an Address, a structured compound data type, as well as individual address elements.
>
> Using API 30.0 and later, standard addresses are available in the SOAP and REST APIs as a compound field of type Address, a structured data type that combines the following fields.
>
> - Accuracy
> - City
> - Country
> - CountryCode
> - Latitude
> - Longitude
> - PostalCode
> - State
> - StateCode
> - Street
>
> ### Retrieving Compound Address Fields
>
> Using compound fields can simplify code that works with addresses, especially for SOQL queries. SOQL SELECT clauses can reference addresses directly, instead of all of the individual component fields.
>
> ```
> SELECT Name, BillingAddress
> FROM Account
> ```
>
> To write code that’s compatible with API versions before 30.0, as well as API 30.0 and above, use the individual fields:
>
> ```
> SELECT Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode,
>        BillingCountry, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude
> FROM Account
> ```

Comment: OP is asking about the bulk API. I do not believe this is supported yet via the bulk API

Comment: @Eric I am surprised the documentation on compound fields seems to ignore that issue. But still, the point is that they need to be queried individually.

Comment: Eric & Adrian, thank you for your answers!!! About my second question - I need to support large organizations with alot of users. Bulk is the sutible API for my mission? do i need to use PK Chunking?

Comment: How many users are you dealing with? If it's less than 10k I think just standard REST is fine honestly.

Comment: I want to be able to query up to 100,000 users.

Comment: Well, it's kind of a separate question. If you want more guidance there, you should post a new one.

Comment: Done: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/query-100-000-users-from-salesforce

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the field "Address". Querying for that field when using the **bulk API** is not supported

You need to select the individual parts of the address

i.e. City, Street

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm

> Also, Bulk API can’t access or query compound address or compound
>   geolocation fields.

Comment: You'd think that should be listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_limitations.htm) as well. I've submitted feedback on the document that it's missing that point.